# Display the elements of [object Text] [object HTMLUListElement]?

Tags: javascript, html

Does someone know how to display the elements of [object HTMLUListElement] ?

thanks,

Bruno

Comment: How you want to display them? What are elements: child nodes or properties of the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following:

```
var myObj; //I'm assuming this variable contains your HTMLUListElement

for (var member in myObj){
    alert(myObj[member]);
}
```

When using a for in, you should really check `hasOwnProperty`, though

```
for (var member in myObj){
    if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(member)){
        alert(myObj[member]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might wanna throw in a `hasownproperty()` check inside the for statement?

Comment: @Exelian: Had already done, probably while you were writing the comment!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want the child nodes:

```
var lis = theObject.children;
for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    console.log(lis[i].innerHTML);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/6WZXE/

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work (nothing happens).

Comment: @Bruno - You'll need to provide more information/code then - if you're not seeing anything, you'll need a console open (Firebug/Chrome Inspector, etc). Otherwise, replace `console.log` with `alert(lis[i].innerHTML);`